# creating site collections using SharePoint management shell 2013

Tags: powershell, site-collection, 2013

I am creating Site Collections for Testing SharePoint. I am using Host Named Site Collection to do that instead of the path based site collection addressing.

For that

1. Got a reference to the HNSC web application which I created before using web application management.
2. created a non-templated site at the root of the web applications for workflow to connect.

   ```
   New-SPSite -Name "Root HNSC Site Collection" -Url "http://vspserver -HostHeaderWebApplication $hnscWebApp -OwnerAlias "vspserver \Administrator"
   ```
3. but when I try to create a Team site by using the following scrpit:

   ```
   New-SPSite -Name "VSPServer Intranet" -Url "http://intranet.vspserver" –HostHeaderWebApplication $hnscWebApp -Template "STS#0" -OwnerAlias "vspserver\Administrator"
   ```

I get this error message:

```
    New-SPSite : Cannot find an SPWebApplication object that contains the
    following Name, Id, or Url: http://intranet.vspserver.test-lab.local.
    At line:1 char:1
    + New-SPSite -Name "SPServer Intranet" -Url
    "http://intranet.vspserver.test-lab.lo ...
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletNewSite:
       SPCmdletNewSite) [New-SPSite], SPCmdletPipeBindException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSite
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the URL say? Post full stack trace please

Comment: ULS log, not url

Comment: @ Anders Rask, I don't get what you mean. where can I get that from?

Comment: @user1847609 You can find exceptions in the ULS log. Here is a guide: [View diagnostic logs in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff463595.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a template variable and use Get-SPWebTemplate instead. Begin with asigning your $template variable by this script:

```
$template = Get-SPWebTemplate "STS#0"
```

Then use the $template variable in your creation script:

```
New-SPSite -Name "VSPServer Intranet" -Url "http://intranet.vspserver" 
–HostHeaderWebApplication $hnscWebApp -Template $template 
-OwnerAlias "vspserver\Administrator"
```

Reference: [Create a site collection in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263094.aspx)

Comment: I tried that but getting the same Error message.

Comment: The point is I cannot create a team site. I though I create a new URL but it seems from the Error that it cannot be found, so is it something that I create beforehand?

Comment: This does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is that the cmdlet cannot properly pipe SPWebApplication object. (at least from the error) If you try:

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication http://intranet.vspserver.test-lab.local.
```

You should get an error as well, maybe more descriptive this time.

Other thing is that I can defo see an issue with your URL, is it correct that it resolves to the '(...)local.' That dot/'.' on the end looks quite suspicious.

The other issue you may be having (if I understand correctly) is that you have created a root site. Then you try to create a team site at 'http://intranet.vspserver' which is root site. You cannot overwrite a site collection this way, you should be creating new at 'http://intranet.vspserver/sites/teamsite'.

Other bit to check is how is your host file wired you should wire the http://intranet.vspserver to the local host (pretty normal for lab and dev machines)